# Spring boot 2.4 Neo4j 6.0 Null value map to boolean primitive changed

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Prior to SB2.4neo4j6, if i had a **boolean node property, and it had no value saved** in the db, it was automatically set as false at mapping into the @Node marked pojo and **caused no problem**.

In this new **Spring boot 2.4 neo4j 6** however it throws an exception that **null cannot be mapped to boolean value**.

Should i now set up some Null to boolean conversion or what should i do?
Tried with **"GenericConverter"** and also with  **Neo4jPersistentPropertyConverter with @ConvertWith** on the property in manymany ways with Boolean and NullValue and Object and so on.

**What would be a way to solve this?**(cant do database update to give all non existent booleans a value)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do a database update to set the value. Have you looked at Liquibase?

https://www.liquibase.org/

With that, a changeset like this:

```
<query>
   MATCH (n:WhateverNode) WHERE NOT exists(n.flag) SET n.flag=false RETURN n
</query>
```

Would cleanly update your database so that you don't need any tricky converters.

Comment: sure it would be possible, for whatever reason tho, i am not allowed to by someone who knows more about the project/db as i do. In the end i just changed the primitives to the wrapper class(Boolean), and gave them e getter which returns the default value if its null. Definietly not a nice solution/one that i wanted, but it works.